# Extract gzip content from raw http response

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, web, networking

I try to do http(not **https** scheme, i.e url is `http://www.example.com`) `get` simply by `socket` module, then I `recv` response which contains all tranferred data from server(header and body with gzip encoded).Then I try to extract gzipped body content. I guess this content should start at `\x1f\x8b\x08` , but I don't know where it should end.Any help?

Below is my raw response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Header Part\r\n
\r\n
some_number_here\r\n
\x1f\x8b\x08 ......
......\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n
```

Comment: data should start when body starts - it means after first empty line (\r\n\r\n). In header could be line "content-size" with size of data in body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that in the Header part you have an `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header.

This is an `HTTP/1.1` response, not an `HTTP/1.0`, and understanding chunked transmission is required in the 1.1 version of HTTP.

You have two solutions:

- tell the server you do not understand `HTTP/1.1` by using `HTTP/1.0` in your requests, on the first line, like in `GET /foo HTTP/1.0`

  - implement the chunked transmission parsing.

The parsing is not so hard. Instead of a raw body you have a body splitted in parts (chunks); each part start with the chunk size (the `some_number_here\r\n` stuff), it's an hexadecimal number(warning `10` means `16`, `1c` means 28).

Then you have the raw chunk content.

Then the next chunk.

Until you reach the last chunk, which is advertized with a 0 size (`0\r\n\r\n`).

Warning: the server may take some time between chunks, you have to keep reading the socket until you see this last chunk.

PS: do not try to implement HTTP with sockets for something that would go into production later, there are a lot of HTTP clients available, even in python, and it's a very huge job to get something secure and robust.

Comment: Yes.I have found the answer by wireshark. Then I check Wikipedia *chunked transfer* to get verification.  PS:Why shouldn’t we implement http by socket?Doesn’t modules such as *http* and *urllib* implement this by socket?

Comment: Yes, What I mean is do not try to redo the huge work done in these modules. If you want to implement an HTTP reader from scratch you'll need to read several RFC (HTTP/1.1, url parsing, etc.) and chances are great that you'll make some huge security mistakes. Reuse existing work.